# Change WPF mainwindow label from another class and separate thread

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, mainwindow

Im working on a WPF application. I have a label called "Status_label" in `MainWindow.xaml`. and I want to change its content from a different class (signIn.cs).
Normally I'm able to do this

```
var mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow) as MainWindow;
mainWin.status_lable.Content = "Irantha signed in";
```

But my problem is,when I'm trying to access it via different thread in signIn.cs class, it gives an error:

```
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Can I solve this by using `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>{..........` or something else?

**EDIT:**
I'm gonna call this label change action from different class as-well-as separate thread

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,312,0,0" Name="status_lable" Width="361"/>
```

**SignIn.cs**

```
    internal void getStudentAttendence()
    {
        Thread captureFingerPrints = new Thread(startCapturing);
        captureFingerPrints.Start();
    }

void mySeparateThreadMethod()
{
    var mainWin = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(window => window is MainWindow) as MainWindow;
    mainWin.status_lable.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(()=> mainWin.status_lable.Content ="Irantha signed in"));
}
```

line var mainWin return error`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Please guide me,

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps, because this question has been answered a hundered times. Some 'googling' would provide you a proper solution.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I resolved my question, hope somebody will need this. But don't know whether this is the optimized way.

In my **mainWindow.xaml.cs** :

```
    public  MainWindow()
    {
      main = this;
    }

    internal static MainWindow main;
    internal string Status
    {
        get { return status_lable.Content.ToString(); }
        set { Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { status_lable.Content = value; })); }
    }
```

from my **SignIn.cs** class

```
 MainWindow.main.Status = "Irantha has signed in successfully";
```

This works fine for me.
You can find more details from here, [Change WPF window label content from another class and separate thread](https://iranthajayasekara.com/blog/change-wpf-window-label-content-from-another-class-and-a-separate-thread.html)

cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

try below snippet:

```
status_lable.Dispatcher.Invoke(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but my issue is due to different thread.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean.Do you wish to do so in separate thread? You can use status_lable.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...) or 
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {status_lable.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);}); if you want to be more reponsive

Comment: But my error return from var mainWin line, Can I access mainWindow's status_label by another way? I edited the question can u pls check it?

Comment: These are two questions actually. You mixed them but your title is about threaded access. I think I have answered your question about threaded access. As for the accessing the status_label, you have to provide a function or property so that you can access it in your mainwin class. For instance, in your user control class (where the status_label is located), you can provide a property called StatusCtrl to offer public/internal access.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answers, they led me in the right direction. I ended up with this simple solution:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static MainWindow main;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                        
        main = this;
    }
}
```

Then in my eventhandler in another class that runs in a different thred:

```
internal static void pipeServer_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow.main.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
        {
            MainWindow.main.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }));
    }
```

This to show the minimized window when i message is received via a namedPipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!  I wound up with a slightly different solution, but you definitely pointed me in the right direction with your answer.

For my application, I have a lot of controls in main, and most of the method calls on main were occurring from within the scope of main, so it was simpler to use the default { get; set } within MainWindow.xaml.cs (or to just define the controls in XAML).

In my parent window's code-behind, I launch the MainWindow in a separate thread like this (simplified example).  The key is to define main globally, even though it is instantiated inside of  Window_Loaded():

```
    public ParentWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MainWindow main;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread otherThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            main = new MainWindow();
            main.Show();

            main.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                main.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

        otherThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        otherThread.Start();

    }
```

Then in my MainWindow code-behind, I just interact with the controls as though it is a simple single-threaded application (there is no control of the parent thread from the child thread in my case).  I can, however, control main from the parent thread like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            main.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate () 
                {
                    main.myControl.myMethod(); 
                }));

        }
```

By doing it this way, I avoid the complexity of defining everything in code-behind and using the dispatcher from within the code-behind of MainWindow.xaml.cs.  There are only a few spots in my application where I modify main from the parent window, so this was simpler for me, but your approach seems equally valid.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Simple trick without use `Dispatcher.Invoke`: In your `Window` class put this:

```
public partial class MyWindow: Window
{
    public static MyWindow mywin;
    [...]

    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mywin = this;
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

Next in your second class to call the properties you need to add your window name + the label that you've assigned. This is an example:

```
internal class MySecondClass
{
    internal void ChangeAValue()
    {
        MyWindow.mywin.ATextBox.Text = "Some text"; // I'm changing for example the text for a textbox in MyWindow.
    }
}
```